# how to find best element in bag in knapsack

Tags: c#, algorithm, knapsack-problem

how can I find best items in the bag in KNAPSACK problem in recursive mode with C#?

I have tried to collect indexes which function return larger value for them but i did not seem to work....

```
static int recursiveknapsnack(int i,int W) {
    if (i < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (wt[i] > W) {
        return recursiveknapsnack(i - 1, W);
    } else {
        return Math.Max(recursiveknapsnack(i-1, W),recursiveknapsnack(i-1,W - wt[i])+val[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with the best element? The knapsack problem is NP-hard so calculating the best element requires a backtracking algorithm.

Comment: suppose i have 10 items and i have calculated the most benefit.....how can i find items the thief should take ?

Comment: Can you show the code that you have so far?

Comment: @alinajimi: if the thief can only take one element, you should iterate over the list of items, check if the thief can pick them, and if so, take the one with the maximum value...

Comment: @radio static   int recursiveknapsnack(int i,int W)
        {
        
        
            if (i < 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else     if (wt[i] > W)
            {
            
                return recursiveknapsnack(i - 1, W);
            }
            else
            {
            

               return Math.Max(recursiveknapsnack(i - 1, W),recursiveknapsnack(i - 1, W - wt[i]) + val[i]);
            }



        }

Comment: @CommuSoft could u please give me an example in c# or any other language ?

Comment: The bookkeeping seems to be wrong. You add the `val` to the leftover weight?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it depends on which Knapsack problem you aim to solve, but if it is the default one, you should separate the *weight* aspects from the *value*-aspects, thus:

```
static int recursiveknapsnack(int i,int W, int v) {
    if (i < 0 || w <= 0) {
        return v;
    } else if (wt[i] > W) {
        return recursiveknapsnack(i-1,W,v);
    } else {
        return Math.Max(recursiveknapsnack(i-1,W,v),recursiveknapsnack(i-1,W- wt[i],v+val[i]));
    }
}
```

And call it with:

```
recursiveKnapsack(n,W,0);
```

with `n` the number of items and `W` the total capacity of the Knapsack.

Note however that this recursive algorithm is far from optimal. The *knapsack* problem is *pseudo-polynomial* using a *dynamic programming* approach, one can achieve a way more efficient algorithm.

**EDIT**: in case you want to calculate the bag and not the maximum value itself, you can store the optimal value and bag:

```
int[] wt;//the weights
int[] val;//the values

static bool[] solveKnapsack (int W) {
    int n = wt.length;
    bool[] knapsack = new bool[n];
    bool[] opt = null;
    int vopt = 0;
    recursiveknapsnack(n-1,W,0,knapsack,ref vopt,ref opt);
    return opt;
}

static void recursiveknapsnack(int i, int W, int v, bool[] knapsack, ref int vopt, ref bool[] kopt) {
        if (i < 0 || w <= 0) {
            if(v > vopt) {
                vopt = v;
                kopt = (bool[]) knapsack.Clone();
            }
        } else if (wt[i] > W) {
            return recursiveknapsnack(i-1,W,v);
        } else {
            return Math.Max(recursiveknapsnack(i-1,W,v,ref vopt, ref kopt),recursiveknapsnack(i-1,W-wt[i],v+val[i],ref vopt,ref kopt));
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response....but i still did not get to how to get the items the thief should take? how should i change the code?

Comment: @alinajimi: ah you don't want the maximum value, but calculate the bag itself?